# CreateEventProc has crash on vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, event-handling

I want to add an event to a sheet in Excel using VB.net
I've written the following code for this
But I encountered the problem in the Specified line

Please help me

this program has crashed on line 22

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Vbe.Interop
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim excelApplication As New Excel.Application
        Dim excelWorkbooks As Excel.Workbooks = excelApplication.Workbooks
        Dim excelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = excelWorkbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet)
        Dim excelWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = excelWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        excelApplication.Visible = True
        Dim VBComp As Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.VBComponent
        Dim CodeMod As Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.CodeModule
        Dim LineNum As Long

        VBComp = excelApplication.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(excelWorkSheet.Index)
        CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
        With CodeMod
            LineNum = .CreateEventProc("Active", "Worksheet")'**Crash: Event handler is invalid**
            LineNum = LineNum + 1 : .InsertLines(LineNum, " ")
            LineNum = LineNum + 1 : .InsertLines(LineNum, "Msgbox(""Hi"")")
        End With
        'Save and quit
        excelWorkbook.SaveAs("F:\MyVBAExcelFile.xlsm", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled)

        excelApplication.Quit()

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkbooks)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkbook)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApplication)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

**Active** is a state not an event, you should try **Activate** to make it work. The error is thrown when an event does not exist (like Active).

Comment: how to active it?

Comment: change "Active" to "Activate"